# if condition changed by its content

Tags: php, post

I encountered relay interesting problem.

I have this condition in external file which is called and after process code redirects to page set via `BACKLINK` post parameter like this.

```
if(isset($_POST['secureLogout'])) 
{
    $_POST['backlink'] = '/';
    session_destroy();
    System::WriteLog('Session has been destroyed');
}
```

and even I don't post `secureLogout` parameter it still trigger, so I tried to `var_dump` POST variables, there is no `secureLogout` parameter.

so then I tried put my POST inside condition with exit to see what is in my post..

```
if(isset($_POST['secureLogout'])) 
{
    var_dump($_POST); exit();

    $_POST['backlink'] = '/';
    session_destroy();
    System::WriteLog('Session has been destroyed');
}
```

and NOW magic happens `It does not trigger`  the code continue and everything works fine, but i cant logout now directly cause of exit before session destroy.

So basically how is it even possible that content inside IF has any effect on condition??

It is completely UN-logical and I lost my patience, I tried change post names, conditions but result is same.

If there is exit inside condition, condition is false, if there is no exit condition is true.

*EDIT*

I changed if condition to $_POST['secureLogout'] == 'secureLogout' problem still remained then i changed condition to

```
$_POST['secureLogout'] == 'secureLogout123'
```

which has to be false everytime and it is session is not destroyed, so I put exit inside again and changed condition back

```
$_POST['secureLogout'] == 'secureLogout'
```

with exit, condition does not tirgger so $_POST secureLogout parameter is either **different** or is not **set**

**I removed exit** and session been destroied...

Comment: What is your `if` condition..?  It obviously returns 'false' as it is moving to your `elseif`  which must be 'true' as the code inside it is executing.

Comment: What you describe is impossible. `even I DO NOT post secureLogout parameter it still trigger` no it doesn't.

Comment: changed elseif to if to match the topic, problem remained same

Comment: Too less information to comment anything on this. Logically, it cannot happen that way.

Comment: Cthulu thats exactly why I am angry, System::WriteLog method wrote log to my file so it HAS TO BE triggered and when i PUT exit or die inside log did not changed.

Comment: Make it write $_POST content to log then inside this condition (json_encode'd for example). But I can tell you that `secureLogout` will be there (maybe empty string) or nothing will (which will mean some other piece of code writes `Session has been destroyed`).

Comment: 10.08.2015 09:52:43 - Session has been destroyed :1:{s:12:"secureLogout";s:12:"secureLogout";} from serialized post we can see there is clearly set post, so after log i put exit then die and nothing happens not even log

Comment: It is impossible that content changes the `if()` statement behaviour. Provide more information or is impossible to help you

Comment: Or better yet, install php-xdebug and, well, debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the amount of parameters available to be post in phpini. Maybe you are trying to post too many variables which overflow the capacity and cause the script to crash.

Answer (score 0):

With this information is impossible to occur that you are saying, but I think that your problem is the `isset()` and not the `if()` statement. The if statement doesn't change its behaviour depending of the content. Maybe, `secureLogout` is isset, but is empty, and here you are your possible solution:

```
if(!empty($_POST['secureLogout']))  {
    // empty returns true when is not set, when it's zero values, empty values, etc.
}
```

See this:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Good luck!

Comment: changed condition to $_POST['secureLogout'] == 'secureLogout' with exit not happens, without exit happens

Comment: if you don't push more information, is impossible to help you. You have another piece of code that you don't want to show us. Please, write what var_dump() returns or make a phpfiddle: http://phpfiddle.org and share us.

Answer (score 0):

`isset` return true only if it contains some value. In other words, it returns true **only** when the variable is **not null**. Consider that 0 and "" are a value.

You could try to use `if(!empty($_POST['secureLogout']))`. `empty` does the same as `isset` but checks if the variable is **empty**. 0 and "" are différent than empty. So empty will return false.

Comment: changed condition to $_POST['secureLogout'] == 'secureLogout' with exit not happens, without exit happens